# Small-memory worker nodes and performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to set up a spark cluster on top of docker swarm running on scavenged hardware. I have in total 50 cpu cores and 67Gb RAM, however, it is spread over 13 physical machines, meaning that a lot of worker nodes will only have 1 or 2 Gb RAM. The physical machines are connected by a single 1Gbit network.

- I have made a simple test program in pyspark that reads msgpack files, filters some rows and writes new files. Each file is 380Mb, and I have made it so that each file is in its own partition in the RDD. With this setup, 61 files takes 32minutes to process. The time to do the same for one file in pure python on one machine is roughly 12s-18s / file, meaning that if I didn't parallelize and just ran it on one machine, it would take ~18 minutes. Is this enormous overhead normal for spark/pyspark?!
- Anything that triggers a shuffle (like groupByKey) grinds to a halt. Is this likely to be limited by my low RAM, or a sign of communication limits between the nodes? How do I find this out?

Is it even possible / sensible to run spark on a hardware platform like mine?

Comment: Considering that Spark overhead alone can exceed 1GB and you need around 0.1GB for minimal Python worker process - probably not (it is not hard to find much leaner solution which would utilize cluster like this). That being said - debugging somone's code, without the code is not going to work either. Would you mind providing a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you have suggestions for an alternative solution, preferably with a similar programming model to RDD:s?

Example code I tried to run: https://github.com/innovationgarage/PortPollution-AISreduction/blob/egil-master/test.py
The input files are 384M each, containing msgpack:ed objects, some of which have a "draught" member, which I'm filtering them for.